# Dynamic multi values query creation that are send throe POST

Tags: jquery, html, forms, post

I have product and product have more then one color! and also the same product can have more then one multicolor set.

Example: the product is "shirt". "Shirt" has colors blue, green, red. Then I need to add to the same "model" "shirt" with others colors black, white, yellow, orange. Then add another color set to same model... etc.

My idea how it should work: I have one color table with all available colors. So I add "shirt" to market and click "add color set" and then the table with all colors opens. I chose colors that I need for the product (first color set), press "save" and it creates color query "name=color_set_1". Then again I press "add color set".... etc.

Problem: I have no idea how can I create those dynamic "name=color_set_?" that contains multicolor that I can send properly throe POST.

Answer (score 1):

Do you try name[]=color_set?

You can send

name[]="pink";
name[]="yellow";...

And later get the array.

Something like this:

```
?model=Shirt&name[1][]=red&name[1][]=black&name[1][]=white&name[2][]=blue&name[2][]=green
```

And with this you will have 2 color sets in a multidimensional array: Color set 1 = red, black and white, and color set 2 = blue and green

Answer (score 0):

I would use PHP to do this for example:

```
<?php
    $colour = $_POST['colour'];
    $model = $_POST['model']
    $set = $_POST['set']

    $name = $colour+"_"+$set+"_"+$model;

   etc....
?>
```